# IntegrityError Django

Tags: python, django

I got suddenly an integrity error: "Duplicate entry 'qw' for key 'username'
 from this model. 1062,

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(User):
 slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)
 description=models.TextField(null=True)
 phone=models.IntegerField(null=True)
 id_verified=models.NullBooleanField()
 picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='media/customer', null=True)
 isWorker=models.BooleanField()

 def save(self,*args,**kwargs):                                         
    self.slug=slugify(self.username)                                   
    super(Customer,self).save(*args, **kwargs)                            
 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Don't inherit from `User` for your custom model. [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) say *"The easiest way to construct a compliant custom User model is to inherit from AbstractBaseUser."*.

Comment: If you are attempting to create a new extended `User` then you might want to check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model.  You probably want to be sub-classing `AbstractUser` (or `AbstractBaseUser` as @gertvdijk has pointed out above)

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, about specifying a custom user model:

> You must then provide some key implementation details:
>
> USERNAME_FIELD
>
> A string describing the name of the field on the User
>   model that is used as the unique identifier. This will usually be a
>   username of some kind, but it can also be an email address, or any
>   other unique identifier. The field must be unique (i.e., have
>   unique=True set in its definition).

So username seems to be unique, at least until you set a custom username field.

Read the docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: it gives anerror in this line  def save(self,*args,**kwargs):